# select query with inner join multiple

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

I can't get all of a customer's orders from different stores, what I want to do is retrieve the information on the store concerned, such as the city of the store, etc..all my other queries work except this one.i use mysql mariadb. here are my select query:
thank you for help.

```
SELECT * 
FROM commandes 
INNER JOIN users ON commandes.id_user= users.id_user 
INNER JOIN boutiques ON commandes.idBoutiques= boutiques.idShop 
WHERE users.number_client = ?"
```

schema database [image]

Comment: Can you show us your table schemas?

Comment: I edited my post with a screenshot of the database @AlexandruBorza

Comment: The table names in the screenshot are different from the query.

Comment: Why is `commandes.idBoutique` a different datatype from `boutiques.idBoutique`?

Comment: yes i wrote them in english for the post @Barmar

Comment: But it's hard to tell which tables are which. Is the English `shops` equivalent to `boutiques` or `patisseries`?

Comment: What's wrong with the query you have? What results are you expecting, what are you getting instead?

Comment: shops = boutique @

Comment: I want to get the coordinates of the store that corresponds to the customer's order

Comment: I don't see linkage in your schema between `commandes` and your `users` table. Rather a `user` has a `reservation` at a `boutique` so the `reservations` table would be the intermediate table needed here.

Comment: You need to use patiseries between commands and users.

Comment: Thank you very much for telling me what to modify, it works @JoelCrypto

Answer (score 0):

the solution:

````
SELECT  * 
FROM commandes 
INNER JOIN users ON commandes.id_user= users.id_user 
INNER JOIN patisseries ON commandes.id_patisserie 
=patisseries.id_patisserie 
INNER JOIN boutiques ON patisseries.idBoutique = boutiques.idBoutique 
WHERE users.numero_client = ?```
````